# AD-B2C Custom Policy - Microsoft Authenticator TOTP valid for more than 30 seconds

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, authenticator

We have used Azure AD-B2C and implemented MFA using custom policy. We have authenticator app as one of the MFA option to login to our application.

We are using Microsoft Authenticator App and it generates the one-time passcode every 30 seconds. However, we are able to login to the application using the old TOTP that's generated before 30 secs.

I have verified checking the validity of the TOTP, but couldn't find any documentation on this. The code generated is sometimes valid up to 3 mins and sometimes up to 5 mins. Is the code not supposed to expire within 30 seconds?

Can you please clarify this, and refer me to any documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per all the documentation, TOTP generates the one-time passcode every 30 seconds, but nothing is mentioned about its expiry time.

As per TOTP algorithm, we can't control its expiry time and as name mentioned its one-time code which can be used only one time.
So even if you are entering the expired code, it is really not expired. It is just expired in the time slice when the app generated it, but Azure AD B2C will accept it within time tolerance (as per you up to 5 mins sometimes).

As this OTP can be used once, B2C will give you error if you try to use it next time.

One more factor is the code generation is based on system time, and while system time of Azure AD B2C can be synchronized with internet time servers, system time of mobile device can be out of sync for various reasons. Thus, Azure AD (B2C) has a time tolerance of to accept Time Based One Time Passwords during verification.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to find appropriate documentation related to this. But in my  experience, the totp verify page (Not registration) allows codes of +/- 90 seconds.

In registration flow, the totp flow accepts code as old as around 24 hours. A common mistake that could happen is reading and writing the secret key while using the new totp flow. If you provide the secretkey value as an input claim to totp verification page, b2c treats it as a registration flow and goes ahead and accepts old codes.

I believe the reason for this to account for time skew in the user's totp device. The time in user's totp device might not be in sync with server time and totp relies on current time to generate the code.

Once you use a code from 2 hours ago for registration and if you try to verify with a new code (current time), the verification will fail. It will expect you to provide a code from 2 hours ago with a tolerance of +/- 90 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Azure MFA allows TOTP code in the range of 900 seconds (-450 and +450 seconds).
Not documented anywhere, found by experimenting